# RouteProvider и контроллеры Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Здравствуйте!
Недавно начал изучать **Angular JS**, поэтому ещё не разобрался во всех тонкостях этого фреймворка.

Сейчас разрабатываю **SPA-приложение**. Настраиваю **routeProvider**, маршрутизация работает. Общее кол-во страниц - 2 штуки, так вот, на одной странице привязка к контроллеру работает, а на другой нет. Помогите разобраться.

**controllers.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('player', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/popular', {
            templateUrl: 'views/popular.html',
            controller: 'PopularCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
});

app.factory('API', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/xbmc.php');
    }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$resource', '$location', 'API','$route',
    function($scope, $resource, $location, API,$route) {


        $scope.title = 'Page 1'

    }]);


app.controller('PopularCtrl',['$scope', '$resource', '$location', 'API', '$route',
    function($scope, $resource, $location, API, $route) {
        $scope.data = API.get({action: 'popular'});

        $scope.title = 'Page 2'

    }]);
```

Comment: что значит привязка к контроллеру? в чем выражается _не работает_? приведите пример шаблонов и основного вида

Comment: приведенный код - работоспособен и не должен вызывать ошибок

Comment: по крайней мере в [`plunkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3JfD8NtZ8wSoQqZepxR?p=preview) все работает